# Opera browser - cookie editor

Tags: cookies, opera

Is there any tool like WebDeveloper plugin for Firefox? I'm most interested in cookie manipulation, especially in creating cookies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use [dragonfly](http://www.opera.com/dragonfly/), you can invoke it by the "CTRL+SHIFT+I" shortcut or by menu (Page> Developer Tools> Opera dragonfly ), then use the "Storage" tab (The "Cookies" sub tab should be the default), double click on an entry to edit it.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I've been looking for.

Comment: Currently there is no Dragonfly on the latest `WebKit-based` Opera but they saying that it might be ported soon http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14942925/will-operas-dragonfly-and-extentions-still-exist-in-webkit-world

Answer (score 2):

We're working on a new cookie manager for Opera Dragonfly 1.0. It is close to being finished, but will likely not be enabled until the next version of Opera is released (due to a bug when deleting cookies).

The new version will show more information (all the various fields) and give you more control.

You can also edit and delete cookies from within Opera itself (right click, edit site preferences, then select the cookie tab). This works well, but doesn't allow you to add cookies.

Comment: Nice job with Dragonfly! Currently I'm still using Firefox Web Developer plugin. It has really simple and easy to use component for adding/removing/modifying cookies. I'm looking forward to see the new interface :)

Answer (score 1):

There is also the "Preferences > Advanced > Cookies > Manage cookies" dialog :)