# will Opera's DragonFly and Extentions still exist in Webkit world?

Tags: webkit, opera, blink, opera-dragonfly

[I just saw that Opera will stop using Presto](http://www.opera.com/press/releases/2013/02/13/), and switches to WebKit, so will DragonFly still exists, or this will be replaced by Chrome Inspector?

And what about Extensions too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There will be no Dragonfly in Opera with WebKit (Blink): 
https://twitter.com/runeh/status/301616059729969152

Comment: thank you! this is why the latest update was before 2013 https://github.com/operasoftware/dragonfly

Answer (score 9):

Yes, Opera Dragonfly will still exist. The current beta of Opera 15 includes Web Inspector, however, Opera are porting Opera Dragonfly to Blink. It will be included when ready.

Note: I was formally the Product Manager of Opera Dragonfly, before switching companies.

Opera Extensions use a different format for the Blink based Opera. It uses the subset of the Chrome extension model. There is a tool to convert the existing extensions, and documentation: http://dev.opera.com/extension-docs/

Comment: happy to hear that dragonfly will still be here, because working on the same inspector as chrome is boring :p

Comment: @AbdelouahabPp Sure; the web inspector of Chrome don't automaticly re-indent obfuscated file on web-sites nor allow to use the raw console interpreter...

Comment: If opera dragonfly dies, then I will be very unhappy, yes indeed. I've tried the inspectos from all other major browsers, but the usability of dragonfly is superb! It would be very sad if the opera team let dragonfly fly :(

Comment: The latest opera really missing a lot of useful functional that is not available in `WebKit` version of Opera, including the Dragonfly. Now you have to install an extensions to get the missing functional and play around with the `opera:flags`

Comment: a few months have passed since this post and there i still no Dragonfly, the only tool to come even close dragonfly is IE 11 developers tools....