# How to return Dragonfly from Opera 12 to Opera 17?

Tags: browser, opera, opera-dragonfly

I've just installed Opera 17. I'm going to cry.. How can i return Dragonfly debugger into this version of Opera from older version? T_T

Comment: Dragonfly _might_ return to Opera http://stackoverflow.com/a/16846141/946789

Comment: @user2284570 misplaced comment, as it seems ?

Answer (score 3):

Opera Dragonfly doesn't exist in Opera since version 15, and has been replaced with Chromium developer tools (Inspect Element).

You **can** still use it, just install the latest Presto version of Opera (12.16) *Just like me :) cause i love opera dragonfly.*

Comment: @c69 the latest presto based version is [12.50](http://arc.opera.com/snapshot/linux-freebsd/opera-next-12.50-1583.x86_64.rpm "official opera release archive")

Comment: @user2284570 **offtopic**: no, the 12.50 got renamed to 12.10, see: http://my.opera.com/desktopteam/blog/2012/09/12/opera-12-10-beta-candidate, and you can also notice it by comparing build versions (1583 in 12.50 and 1592 in 12.10). There **was** even version for Linux http://snapshot.opera.com/unix/6439_12.10-1592/. _Anyway, first link will also die soon (1st March 2013), when blogs at my.opera will be shut down_.

Comment: Do you have any references?